# add different custom SVG markers to categorized section using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, svg, markers

I am trying to find a way to add different custom SVG markers to the categorized symboling. I would like to have different symbols for different values but unfortunately I cannot find a way to do it using script, that's just straight forward through UI.